# Multiple enclosed-by symbols in SQL*Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am loading a CSV file into an Oracle table. One field in some records is enclosed as `"abc@xyz.com"` and the same field in other records is enclosed as `"'abc@xyz.com'"`. I need to load only `abc@xyz.com`.

I used `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` but it does not help in the second case. Is there a way to specify two symbols in the `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` clause? Or what are the other ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can [apply an SQL operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1226) to trim the leading and trailing single quotes. For example, with a data file containing:

```
"abc@xyz.com"
"'abc@xyz.com'"
'abc@xyz.com'
```

And a control file for a dummy table:

```
LOAD DATA
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE t42
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  EMAIL CHAR(30) "TRIM(BOTH '''' FROM :EMAIL)"
)
```

This loads the stripped values:

```
select * from t42;

EMAIL                        
------------------------------
abc@xyz.com                   
abc@xyz.com                   
abc@xyz.com
```

As you can see, this will load values which are enclosed in single quotes, double quotes, or both - as long as the singles are within the doubles and not the other way around.